# List templates in Sharepoint Online(office 365)

Tags: document-library, office-365

I have created a document library with the setting I want under the site-collection `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub`. I have made it as a template. But I am unable to use this in other site-collection[I Can use it under the contentTypeHub site-collection].

I can see the document library as a template under `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx` I am able to download it.

To upload it in another site-collection I don't see any option to upload on `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/another_site_collection/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx` Is this option removed from office 365 or am I missing something.

Comment: do you want to use it as subsite?

Comment: or you want to create new site collection using that template?